# how to call an activity class in android using fragment object

Tags: android

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

its a fragment object calling different constructor of fragment how can i use constructor or any activity here in place of fragment constructor

Comment: getActivity().startActivity(your intent);

Comment: thanks prag for the answer i m very new to android hope u will help me in future too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the context of this piece of code is within an Activity or Fragment simply call `startActivity(new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class))`. Obviously you have to have the respective Activities for the current fragments.

Comment: thanks for the answer i m very new to android hope u will help me in future too